# How to display image from database using php and html

Tags: php, image, base64

I have this code

```
echo ' <img class="postedImage" src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($Img).'"/ type="image/png"></img><br/>';
```

and I keep getting this display https://gyazo.com/ad1f8096798099d96c0d305a24176182
My database has the images stored in as `longblob`.

When echoing my base64 encode img, I get this which is basically just the images data. The image being uploaded is a png and I still get same results.

```
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
```

Comment: just remove `base64_encode` and then try.

Comment: I get a ton of unicode symbols

Comment: It seems your base64 image code is not properly saved in db.

Comment: you can check here. https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Comment: _Side note:_ The `<img />`-tag is a self closing tag so `</img>` isn't needed. The opening tag should end with a `/` instead (which you seem to have but wrongly located since you've put it directly after the closing `src`-quote)

Comment: thanks @AmitRajput it was to do with my prepared statement, i wasn't using the proper insertions of the images. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally this should work

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $data['image'] ).'"/>';
```

you can also try with **data:$mime**

where $mime:

> mime can be an image of any kind, text, word document, text document,
>   pdf document, e.t.c... data is blob's column content

Please let know if this works for you, thanks.